# Show desktop navbar in desktop view and show a mobile navbar in mobile view

Tags: html, css

I would like to display my navbar that I made for desktop view only when viewing on desktop screens, and show my navbar I made for mobile screens.

I can get it working so only Desktop navbar version shows on desktop, But its a blank space on mobile view.

Here is my current code:

**HTML**

```
<header class="mobile-nav">{% include 'navbar.html' %}</header>
<header class="desktop-nav">{% include 'navbardesktop.html' %}</header>
```

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .desktop-nav {
    display: none!important;
  }
  .mobile-nav {
    display: block;
  } 
}
.mobile-nav {
  display:none!important;
}
```

Comment: First add .mobile-nav {
  display:none!important;
} before media query and don't use important keyword if it's important to use it then use it in media query also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are bumpingup against the concept of cascade in CSS.

The @media rule does not introduce any extra weight to the selectivity so initially the system sees to set the element as display: block but then is finds a request to set it to display: none.

So, change the order of the declarations:

```
.mobile-nav {
  display:none!important;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .desktop-nav {
    display: none!important;
  }
  .mobile-nav {
    display: block;
  } 
}
```

Incidentally, you should be able to remove the !important,though that may depend on any other styling you have.